# AWS CLI configuration ERROR with MacOS Monterey

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, command-line-interface

I am trying to install AWS CLI in MacOS Monterey using `brew install awscli`. (I also tried with pip).
Everything seems to be ok but when I do aws configure I am getting the following error:

```
  from aws.main import main
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aws/main.py", line 23
  print '%(name)s: %(endpoint)s' % {
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I get the same error with any aws command.. Any idea of what is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try locating what commands is running when you enter `aws` in your cli. This can be done  with `which aws`. Go and remove that file and try to reinstall the `awscli`.

Comment: Instead of installing with `brew`, you can download a `pkg` file with auto-installer from: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: The code in that error appears to be for Python 2 -- it's probably trying to install an old version of the AWS CLI.